# How to show only one embed youtube video

Tags: php, youtube

I worked on a function to convert YouTube Video URL to embed HTML code using iframe for a social network script, that's working perfectly.. but, when someone post multiple video link, this is a real havoc and there is multiple embed video.

```
function YoutubeURLtoEmbed {
    $search = '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/a>#x';
    $replace = '<iframe width="500" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);

    return $text;
}
```

My question is : is there a way to limit the number of link can be convert to embed video and after this limit return the link to the video ?

Thanks for your future help.

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) has a fourth parameter `$limit`, use it !

> **mixed** preg_replace ( **mixed** $pattern , **mixed** $replacement , **mixed** $subject [, **int** $limit = -1 [, **int** &$count ]] )

So for example if you want to replace only the first 3 occurences you might use:

`$text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text, 3);`

Comment: Oh snap, thank you, next time I'll read the docs first :|

Mea culpa.